# Apply coupon code on Woocommerce checkout page with AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I moved the Woocommerce coupon form by editing the `review-order.php` based on [this method](https://monalieblog.wordpress.com/2016/08/05/add-coupon-field-in-woocommerce-checkout/)

I would like to know if it's possible to make the coupon code apply with AJAX (without reloading the page) like in the cart page. I don't know where to start, please help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as per your shared link, if you follow the same means you are using the coupon form inside the checkout form, so you should remove the coupon form tag and then use it.

1. Copy woocommerce review-order.php and past inside your active then woocommerce folder.
2. Open review-order.php and past coupon HTML inside table structure like this:

   ```
   <tr class="coupon_checkout">

    <td colspan="2">

        <?php
        if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
        exit; // Exit if accessed directly
        }

        if ( ! wc_coupons_enabled() ) {
        return;
        }

        ?>
        <a href="#" class="showcoupon"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> REDEEM A PROMO CODE/GIFT VOUCHER</a>
        <div class="checkout_coupon" method="post" style="display:none">

            <p class="form-row form-row-first">
            <input type="text" name="coupon_code" class="input-text" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Coupon code', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" id="checkout_coupon_code" value="" />
            </p>

            <p class="form-row form-row-last">
            <input id="checkout_apply_coupon" type="button" class="button" name="apply_coupon" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Apply Coupon', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" />
            </p>
        </div>
    </td>
   </tr>
   ```
3. Add jQuery code either your custom.js file or directly on the footer page like this:

   ```
    <script>
    jQuery(document).on('click','#checkout_apply_coupon', function() {
        // Get the coupon code
        var code = jQuery( '#checkout_coupon_code').val();
        var button = jQuery( this );
        data = {
            action: 'ajaxapplucoupon',
            coupon_code: code
        };
        button.html( 'wait.');
        // Send it over to WordPress.
        jQuery.post( wc_checkout_params.ajax_url, data, function( returned_data ) {
            if( returned_data.result == 'error' ) {
                jQuery( 'p.result' ).html( returned_data.message );
            } else {
                setTimeout(function(){
                //reload with ajax
                jQuery(document.body).trigger('update_checkout');
                    button.html( 'Apply');
                }, 2000);
                console.log( returned_data+code );
            }
        })
    }); 
   </script>
   ```

As I have tested on my checkout page it's working perfectly like this:
https://www.loom.com/share/7dfc833895d248f191ba327cf5290403

4. Optional (if not setup wp_localize_script yet then add into functions.php)

   ```
    function custom_enqueue() {
       wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom.js', array('jquery') ); // optional - if you want to add custom.js then goto theme directory- > js -> and create/add custom.js file 
       wp_localize_script( 'ajax-script', 'wc_checkout_params', array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) ); // setup ajax call url
    }
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_enqueue' );
   ```

Comment: Thanks Rajeev for your answer but unfortunately this didn't work.

I checked the console and I received an error when I press the Apply coupon button :
**Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ()**

From the jQuery library : r.send(i.hasContent && i.data || null

Do you have any idea ?

Comment: @Viko I am receiving a 400 error too. Did you manage to fix it in the end?

Comment: Hi, the issue with your ajax URL(wc_checkout_params.ajax_url), so you need to setup ajax url by using wp_localize_script() first,  then try this.

Comment: Now i have also update my answers and add point 4 for setup wp_localize_script into your themes functions.php

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the snippet below to match your styles.

1. Place the coupon form below in review-order.php or include it from a separate file

   ```
   <form class="checkout_coupon m-0 p-0 border-0 woocommerce-form-coupon grid grid-cols-3" action="<?php echo esc_url(wc_get_cart_url()); ?>" method="post">
       <input type="text" name="coupon_code" class="input-text col-span-2" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e('Coupon code', 'woocommerce'); ?>" id="coupon_code" value=""/>
       <button type="submit" class="theme-button-secondary" name="apply_coupon"><i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i></button>
   </form>
   <script>
     jQuery(document).on('submit', 'form.checkout_coupon', function (e) {
       e.preventDefault()
       var form = jQuery(this)
       form.block({message: null, overlayCSS: {background: '#FFF', opacity: 0.6}})
       jQuery.post(wc_checkout_params.ajax_url, {
         action: 'ajax_apply_coupon',
         coupon_code: form.find('[name="coupon_code"]').val()
       }).done(function () {
         jQuery(document.body).trigger('update_checkout')
         form.unblock()
       }).fail(function (data) {
         jQuery(document.body).trigger('update_checkout')
         form.unblock()
       })
     })
   </script>
   ```

   If you want to include it from different file use this

   ```
   add_action('woocommerce_review_order_after_cart_contents', function () {
       if (is_checkout()) {
           wc_get_template('checkout/coupon.php');
       }
   });
   ```
2. Add your ajax handler with the coupon logic in your function.php

   ```
    function ajax_apply_coupon()
    {
        $coupon_code = null;
        if (!empty($_POST['coupon_code'])) {
            $coupon_code = sanitize_key($_POST['coupon_code']);
        }
        $coupon_id = wc_get_coupon_id_by_code($coupon_code);
        if (empty($coupon_id)) {
            wc_add_notice(__('Sorry, there has been an error.', 'woocommerce'), 'error');
            wp_send_json_error(['message' => __('Sorry, there has been an error.', 'woocommerce')], 400);
        }

        if (!WC()->cart->has_discount($coupon_code)) {
            WC()->cart->add_discount($coupon_code);
        }
        wp_send_json_success(['message' => __('Coupon code applied successfully.', 'woocommerce')], 200);
    }

    add_action('wp_ajax_ajax_apply_coupon', 'ajax_apply_coupon');
    add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_ajax_apply_coupon', 'ajax_apply_coupon');
   ```

Comment: I follow your steps to make the coupon form in a custom template but I always get an error message when I apply the coupon code. No console error, just Sorry, there has been an error from Woocommerce notice

Comment: @Viko did you check your coupon code? seems like coupon_id is empty if you get this error, also what is your woocommerce version? i did this on the latest and was working fine.